# Symlink breaks after usage

Tags: filesystem, symbolic-link, hard-link, openerp

I have OpenERP 7 and I am trying to get the attachments to be saved on the local file system

Configurations on OpenERP are done and are working, but it would only save the files to the installation path `/opt/openerp/server/openerp/filestore`. I only have 1.4 GB of storage left on the drive and it is not enough

I am trying to save them to `/home2/filestore` A symslink did work, but after few files it doesn't save them to the destination path. Does symlink break after time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no symbolic links does not break after time. Hard to answer the question with the details specified. But from what I can gather, `/opt` and `/home2` is different mount points? And you have `hard-link` as a tag.

Hard symbolic links does not work between different mount points, and hard links cannot link directories. See [`info coreutils ln`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ln-invocation.html) for more information.

But back to your problem, just configure `ir_attachment.location` to point to `/home2/filestore` via `Settings` > `Technical` > `Parameters` > `System Parameters`. Read more in this stackoverflow answer: [How to store attachments to local filesystem on 7.0? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960494/3378455)

Comment: OpenERP will always upload files to DB unless the filestore file is inside the installation path of OpenERP
I have tried setting it to `/home2/filestore/` but it did not work

Comment: I tried with a new symlink and it did not break, but even after moving my files from the database to the filesystem the db size did not get reduced, so i am not sure what the benefit was